# Why would Wordpress fail to auto increment new rows for user and usermeta tables?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, auto-increment

I'm trying to wrap my head around this. At first, it looked like a hack to prevent the addition of new users. Then I dug around in the MySQL database and saw that new rows are being created, but they all have the id of zero (0) - the record id is not being auto incremented.

I've replaced all of the files in the "wp-admin" folder, "wp-includes" folder and the key top-level files with copies from the official distribution archive.

I don't see what is causing the system to run incorrectly. What else can I check or change?

Comment: Someone has edited the database, because the `id` value is a primary key by default. I would recommend to use a safe copy of database.

Comment: What if I can't find a safe copy of the database. I inherited a broken site.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Stack Overflow post/answer which I hope to use to fix the problem.

[Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225641/wordpress-database-lost-auto-increment)